# parse.js "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have to insert/update around 2500 records and delete a couple of records in parse using the parse JavaScript SDK. I am using the following code

```
function updateRecords(recordsToAddUpdate, recordsToDelete) {
  var self = this;
  var promises = [];
  if (recordsToAddUpdate.length > 0) {
    promises.push(Parse.Object.saveAll(recordsToAddUpdate));
  }
  if (recordsToDelete.length > 0) {
    promises.push(Parse.Object.destroyAll(recordsToDelete));
  }

  if (promises.length > 0) {
    Parse.Promise.when(promises)
      .then(function() {
        alert("Success");
      }, function(error) {
        alert("error");
      });
  } else {
    alert("nothing to do");
  }
}
```

parse.js internally creates batches of 20 records to insert/update, I can see a series of requests in Firebug and after the last request I get the following error and the Success alert is never displayed.

[image: Firebug error]

I am using Version: 1.3.5 of parse.js

Comment: I think the script is saying, that the function calls it self over and over again

Comment: but this is something being done internally by parse.js